# Python RegEx to report lines a string exists on

Tags: python, arrays, regex, list, line

I am trying to write something up real quick that will find a specific string and report to me what lines those string exist on. I am trying to find exponents so I am looking for "e+" which only occurs on lines that start with AAA, but not ALL the lines with AAA at the start have e+ in them. Currently, my code looks like this:

```
import re
file = raw_input("Enter a file to scan ")
extfile = file+".txt"
#NDoc = raw_input("Enter a file to place results ")
#log = open (NDoc, 'w')
xfile = open(file+".txt")

expcnt = 0
nl = list


for line in xfile:
        line = line.strip()
        n = re.findall('^PV1.+(e\+)')
        if len(n) > 0:
            expcnt = expcnt+1
###            l = line n is on
            nl.append(l)
            for item in nl:
#                log.write(item+"\n")





print (expcnt,"exponenets exist and occur on the following lines:"
For item in nl:
        print item
#print ("Your results can be found in",extfile,".")
```

Basically, I want to know what I need to put on the line with 3 hashtags(#) in order to record the line n was found on and put it into a list. Later, I want to print that list out. NDoc and log at the top are commented out because I am considering print the results to a new page using `from __future__ import print_function`, but that can be ignored for now. So I am trying to put all line numbers into the list nl and all of the exponent strings into the list el (though list el is just for me to double check things and wont be used later).

Any assistance would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Edit:

```
import re
file = raw_input("Enter a file to scan ")
extfile = file+".txt"
#NDoc = raw_input("Enter a file to place results ")
#log = open (NDoc, 'w')
xfile = open(file+".txt")

expcnt = 0
nl = list


for line_num, line in enumerate(xfile):
        line = line.strip()
        n = re.findall('^PV1.+(e\+)')
        if len(n) > 0:
            expcnt = expcnt+1
            l = line_num
            nl.append(l)
            for item in nl:
#                log.write(item+"\n")





#print (expcnt,"exponenets exist and occur on the following lines:"
for item in nl:, does anyone know why that would occur?
    print item
#print ("Your results can be found in",extfile,".")
```

For some reason this is returning an error "Expected an indented block" at `for itme in nl:`

Comment: the "expected an indented block" error is because you didn't put anything after the `for item in nl:` line. you can't declare a for loop without doing something and a commented line doesn't count.

Comment: Oh, thank you, haha, that was a silly mistake, forgot to uncomment something out. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already reading the file line by line, you could use `enumerate`.

```
for line_num, line in enumerate(xfile):
```

instead of

```
for line in xfile:
```

Comment: I made an edit above, could you let me know if the code I have set up is formatted appropriately as well as why it wouldn't be working currently?

Comment: Nvm, got it! Thanks for everything!